# Facing an error while updating my Ubuntu. showing that I am missing a file

Tags: sudo

The error i am getting while updating my Ubuntu:
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386', W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386', E:The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Zj2.png)

I tried:
sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade